# How do I get the sum of all my inputs for a credit limit program?

Tags: java

The java program I am completing is asking me "Ask the user to enter the price of 5 purchased items.  Your credit limit is $150.  The program will calculate the total cost of the items and print out the total cost, and print out whether you are approved or declined". I included the main part of code I have so far.

```
int totalPrice;
int creditLimit;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

    System.out.println("Enter total price of item: ");
    totalPrice = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter credit limit: ");
    creditLimit = input.nextInt();
}

int sum = ???
System.out.println("The total cost of all items is: " +sum);
```

The question marks indicate what I'm confused about.  I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or totally off.  After I get the total cost of the items purchased, how do I show if the user is approved or declined?

Comment: Your code as currently written is going to redundantly ask for the credit limit five times. Move that outside of the loop. Your code needs to **add** each item's price to `totalPrice` in the loop - right now you're *overwriting* its value every time.

Comment: (I also fixed your indenting.)

Comment: Actually, what is the point of asking user for a limit at al? It is provided in task and it looks like constant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add all items prices first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int totalPrice = 0;
    int creditLimit;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter total price of item: ");
        totalPrice += input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter credit limit: ");
    creditLimit = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The total cost of all items is: " + totalPrice);
    System.out.println("Your credit limit is : " + creditLimit);
    System.out.println("Evaluation result: " + (totalPrice > creditLimit ? "declined" : "approved"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First since your credit limit is a constant, declare it as a constant variable. Then since you need to ask for price of each item from the user add that in a loop. Then after the loop compare the sum with the credit limit and show if it is approved or not. Refer to below code segment

```
int totalPrice = 0;
final int CREDIT_LIMIT = 150;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter the price of your item " + i + ": ");
    totalPrice += input.nextInt();
}

if(CREDIT_LIMIT > totalPrice){
    System.out.println("Declined");
} else{
    System.out.println("Approved");
}
```